# PCIe Bus Error Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04

I bought recently a computer and installed ubuntu but get this error when ubuntu is booting

```
[   91.167119] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e0(Receiver ID)

[   91.167122] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00000001/00002000

[   91.167130] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
```

What is it?

is It bad?

How to fix it?

Comment: You might try a `lspci` command in `terminal` to see if you can identify what device is throwing the error. Look for device `00:1c.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same PCIe BusError messages in boot and spamming my logs on Asus x550v (Skylake cpu).

Try this:

Current workaround is to add `pci=noaer` to your kernel command line:

1) edit `/etc/default/grub` and and add `pci=noaer` to the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. It will look like this:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"`

2) run `sudo update-grub`

3) reboot

from [Workaround here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1521173)

note: If `pci=noaer` doesnt work try use `pci-nomsi` instead.