# PCIe Bus error (nomodeset, pci=nomsi, noaer: do not work!)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, system-installation, pcie

I own an Asus laptop, cpu 7300HQ, NVIDIA Geforce GTX 950M, 250 Gb HDD allocated for Windows, 250 GB free.

I can't install Ubuntu in dual boot with Windows 10: the usual, boring problem: "PCIe Bus error"! I tried to apply this solution:[PCIe Bus Error Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911296/pcie-bus-error-ubuntu-16-04) but it doesn't work.

I access the live and after two seconds everything is blocked. I try to install and at some point it freezes everything. I know, I know: disable secure boot, fast boot, check image integrity, etc. I tried with Ubuntu and Ubuntu-Mate 18.04, 19.04, 16.04.6. With Ubuntu 16 I was able to install it but it was all slow so I preferred to delete all the partitions.

In the past I had some minor difficulties installing Ubuntu in this and other computers but I patiently solved it without disturbing the community. This time I'm really desperate: for the past ten days I've been downloading Ubuntu distro and other derivatives (for example Ubuntu Mate).
I had also tried to format the entire hard drive, deleted windows and then reinstalled Bios firmware updated and again windows from 0. Nothing!

Comment: Try, bootoption `pcie_aspm=off`